Should I be concerned about this crack in our bedroom ceiling?
I recently noticed a hairline-type crack in our bedroom ceiling extending from the wall to the light fixture roughly three quarters the way across the room. Is this something to be concerned about? Thank you


Well, stuff does crack. What is above it?

Our attic and then our slanted/shingled roof above that.

Have a look in the attic, if all the trusses (or other structure)  near that crack look good it's probably noting to worry about

It's possible it's just a drywall joint.
